# Google Sheets: How to deal with filtered views when moving rows and sorting between sheets?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtered

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

I have a sheet where I've cobbled together a script that moves a row on edit of a certain value, and then does a multi-sort of the involved sheets so that the row is in order on the new sheet. Works great.

However, now asking if I can make this work with filters. This is where things go wonky. When a filters is engaged, the sort function wrecks the filter when they move a row. Also, the filtered bracket shrinks, and though rows get sorted, and end up within the filtered bracket, others get pushed out, etc. It's a bit hard to explain, so here are two examples:

Script functioning in an unfiltered sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uwge7eS6DXJvbNi-7kRY9djg4Cq2r4QO9BeyNjnhkCg/edit?usp=sharing

Script functioning and wrecking filters: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fXJ8_5bqYCOpm6PlModT-GpymL8zrS0NXkhSYweZX6Y/edit?usp=sharing

(you can turn the filters off and on to reset it if you need to)

When a row is moved can it be sorted within the active filtered set? I'm not sure this is possible. Is it?

My work around would be to have the sorting functions execute onOpen so that they don't disrupt anyones filtered data, but this sheet has a fair number of users, and so I'm not sure if it's ever closed. Any other suggestions?

I appreciate your time and consideration. Thank you. I hope I can return the favour one day.

Here is the script:

```
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:F99"
SORT_ORDER= [
  {column: 4, ascending: true},
  {column: 5, ascending: true}];

function onEdit(event) {
  movethings1(event);
  sortthings1()
  sortthings2();
}

function movethings1(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(r.getColumn() == 2 && ( r.getValue() == "paid" || r.getValue() == "unpaid"
  || r.getValue() == "pending") ) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet;
    if(r.getValue() == "paid")
      targetSheet= ss.getSheetByName("Paid");
    else if(r.getValue() == "unpaid")
      targetSheet= ss.getSheetByName("Unpaid");
    else if(r.getValue() == "pending")
      targetSheet= ss.getSheetByName("Unpaid");
    
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);}
}

  function sortthings1() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Unpaid");
    var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);}

 function sortthings2() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paid");
    var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
    ss.toast('done that thing you wanted');}
```

Comment: Welcome back to [so]. Please remove the "noise" from the question (i.e. the mention that you lost your job and old SO account) . You might also remove the mentions of your coworker as they do not make the question more clear. The last part "Also, for those who are interested, here is a working google apps script for moving rows between..." also should be removed as it's not related to what you are asking. You might post that as an answer to a question that ask for that.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for the edit suggestions. Done.

Comment: FWIW, Both your links are the same and doesn't show a difference.  That being said, I think I understand the issue. However, filterviews are done local in the browser rather than on the serverside. So it's unlikely that you'll find a satisfactory solution to the issue.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you. I've updated the link. I seem to have misspoke when saying Filtered Views as it's just turning the Data>Filter on and then applying a filter to that data - which creates a bracket around the data set.

Comment: If my understanding for your question is correct, I think that in your case, the filter is the basic filter. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters#basic_filter) By the way, I cannot understand about `When a row is moved can it be sorted within the active filtered set?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your response. Currently, if a row is moved from one sheet to another sheet, it ends up at the bottom of the sheet it was moved to. Without the sort function it ends up outside of any active filter. The sort function then moves it within the green box of the filter, but of course disrupts the filter by sorting the sheet. Can the row be moved to the new sheet and then sorted into the range of the active filter?

Comment: May be `.removeFilter()` and  create it back again over the whole range.

Comment: Have you created your filter [manually](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that [@TheMaster 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156093/google-sheets-how-to-deal-with-filtered-views-when-moving-rows-and-sorting-betw?noredirect=1#comment111705326_63156093) is suitable for your situation.

Comment: @TheMaster The problem with removing the filter is that it's not my filter. I don't use them, but another person who is using the same sheet does, and though they are requesting the move and sort functions, they are unhappy with how it wrecks their filters.

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf - yes, I believe they are creating them manually through Data>Create a Filter

Comment: Remove it and recreate it. It'll be gone just for a second or less.

Comment: Have you consider then updating your filter with [```setColumnFilterCriteria```](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria) everytime a new row is added so that you avoid rows getting out of the range?